# Strip Metadata out of JSON Twitter Feed Output and Link Tweets in PHP (1.1 with OAuth)

Tags: php, json, twitter, oauth

I'm switching this twitter feed that I used to have to the new(er) v1.1 API that uses OAuth.

I got the feed server side using a [Github project](https://github.com/abraham/twitteroauth) someone had done and then outputted it into a variable and echoed it. Only thing is that I'm not familiar with JSON.

```
require_once("twitteroauth/twitteroauth/twitteroauth.php"); //Path to twitteroauth library
 
$twitteruser = "goinnative";
// removed token and related variables for this example
 
function getConnectionWithAccessToken($cons_key, $cons_secret, $oauth_token, $oauth_token_secret) {
  $connection = new TwitterOAuth($cons_key, $cons_secret, $oauth_token, $oauth_token_secret);
  return $connection;
}
 
$connection = getConnectionWithAccessToken($consumerkey, $consumersecret, $accesstoken, $accesstokensecret);
 
$feed = $connection->get("https://api.twitter.com/1.1/statuses/user_timeline.json?screen_name=".$twitteruser."&count=".$notweets);

echo $feed;
```

That's great and all, but now I have two issues:

1. There seems to be an error at the bottom of my JSON feed. It gives me a line number but no error information and it looks like a PHP error. Any ideas? Full paste of JSON here: http://pastebin.com/0Ba6cwY2
2. Can I put this JSON output into an array or something and then strip everything but the actual tweet content and links?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved the issue. I didn't realize my feed was already in a PHP array. Therefore solving my issue was as simple as echoing all the [text] pockets of that array in a foreach loop.

```
$tweets = $connection->get("https://api.twitter.com/1.1/statuses/user_timeline.json?screen_name=".$twitteruser."&count=".$notweets);
$tweetOutput="";
foreach ($tweets as $tweets) {
        $tweetOutput .= $tweets->text."<span class='tweetSeperator'>"."&nbsp; &bull; &nbsp;"."</span>";
}
```

After outputting the tweet all I had to do was linkify (http's, mentions and hashtags):

```
function linkifyTweet($statusText)
{
  $statusText = preg_replace('/(https?:\/\/\S+)/', '<a href="\1">\1</a>', $statusText);
  $statusText = preg_replace('/(^|\s)@(\w+)/', '\1@<a href="http://twitter.com/\2">\2</a>', $statusText);
  $statusText = preg_replace('/(^|\s)#(\w+)/', '\1#<a href="http://search.twitter.com/search?q=%23\2">\2</a>', $statusText);
  return $statusText;
}
echo linkifyTweet($tweetOutput);
```